# How to use sqlplus and sqlldr in a script file?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus, sql-loader

I am using sqlplus to get data from a remote database table and then using sqlldr to insert that data into some other table. I have written a shell script to do this. The sqlplus option is working but the sqlldr command is not working, although I have been able to insert using it from command prompt but it seems not be working in file.

Here's my script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #script to get 5 minutes of data from FCT table and insert into LOCAL table
 sqlplus -s user/passs@FCT_DB <<EOF
 SET TERMOUT OFF
 SET LINESIZE 300
 SET HEAD OFF
 SPOOL export.csv
 SELECT X FROM Y
 SPOOL OFF
 EXIT
 EOF
 ! SQLLDR usr/pass@LOCAL_DB CONTROL=loader.ctl ERRORS=5000
```

The export.csv is created correctly. loader.ctl is also correct.

Also, whenever the script runs it shows data fetched on shell. I have searched that SET TERMOUT OFF helps not to display it, but it also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Is there any error?

Comment: No error, the control is not reaching till the sqlldr statement, I have tried to use echo after exit and it didn't print anything

Comment: why the exclamation mark? After EXIT in the here document you have exited sqlplus and are in the shell. So you should not use ! to execute a external command.

Comment: There should be an error. At the least SQLLDR will give 'command not found'. Or have you created an alias SQLLDR for sqlldr? The ';' is missing after 'SELECT X FROM Y'.

Comment: I have got it working, by creating two separate files, one for sqlplus and another for sqlldr. @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe yes itr had given error for SQLLDR , but because it didn't reach that command so it didn't give any error. It exited the script on exit command.